# trouble passing associative array from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am developing an application using `CodeIgniter`. I have created an `associative array` in `javascript` and passing the values to `php` script via `ajax`. In javascript, the values are inserted into the array only if two text fields are not empty. When I pass an empty array to `php` script and echo the variable in Model, I am getting the output as

```
array([0]=> )
```

and if i pass the array by inserting values the response from model is

```
array(['key1']=>['value1'])
```

how can i avoid `[0]`? My script is

```
if(document.getElementById("insertname").value != null &&    document.getElementById("insertnumber").value != null)
{var partner_name = new Object();
 partner_name[document.getElementById("insertname").value] = document.getElementById("insertnumber").value;
}

$.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"",
          data:{Partner_name:partner_name,cus_id:id,cus_message:customermessage},
          success:function(responsee){
            alert("Message Sent and Stored");
            alert(responsee);
          }
        });
```

var dump value

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're using JSON.

Comment: tried it. Still same problem

Comment: can you add a full var_dump of your array to the question?

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify(partner_name) and at server side, json_decode to get in array format

Comment: @JayHardia Yes and still the same problem.

Comment: I think ,i got the problem, put your object declaration outside of if condition.i.e. var partner_name = new Object();

Answer (score 0):

why not doing :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php if(count($array) > 0){ ?>
var _array = "<?php $array; ?>"; //put here what you need this is just an example
<?php }else{ ?>
var _array = "";
<?php } ?>

</script>
```

Comment: This is a nice idea but will create a lot of problems in my code if i use it. Temporarily i have made a fix in the server side. Another thing which i noticed, the ajax call is sending empty variable, which is correct. I think the problem lies in receiving and storing it to php variable.

Comment: @Vinay understood, try posting the var_dump(); of the php data so ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var data = {
    'one' : {
       'child' : '',
    },
    'two' : '',
}

$.ajax({ data : data });
```